# How to remove the Tags from the strings in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tags, nsstring

I want to remove the tags from my string.

For Eg,

```
     NSSTring *str = @"<null>";

     My expected output is null.
```

So i want to remove the HTML tags.

So please guide me.

Thanks.

```
         .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the "<" and ">" symbols then you can use the following code.

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
```